# Error when exporting charts with highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

First time posting on SO so please excuse me if this is a duplicate.
I am trying to export a series of graphs from my web app.
I have attached the exportChart() function to a button which sends the request to the Highcharts export server. Often, but not always, I get the "error when performing chart generation: please check your input data" error. I have tried to get hold of Highcharts support but have not had a response yet. Has anyone come across anything similar? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you save the queries you send, so that you can look at a successful one and compare it to one that fails. If you share that I am sure you will get help very quickly

Comment: If you provide your input data there's more chance people can help

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This happens with the same graph randomly. So I will generate a single graph, try export, get the error. Then generate the same graph afterwards and then it will export? Is this an issue with my input data?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your data input, but it seems very likely.

Comment: Sorry it took a while but please check this for me https://jsfiddle.net/Yosemitespam/f03fg858/19/

Comment: I suppose that the source of the problem are URLs to the images that you create via renderer. When I changed them some other one everything seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/w4ukohzf/ Maybe it's caused by spaces (`%20`) in the addresses.

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed the problem. Appreciate all of the input